# How to connect Windows application to Docker network?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a legacy system. It contains a number of servers running on Linux and a number of GUI clients running on Windows. All the components (servers and clients) are in the same network and they communicate with each other directly. They are identified by ip and port number.

For development purpose, I now run the servers in containers using compose on a Linux host. The servers communicate with each other within the docker network without any issues. However, I have trouble to make the client work with servers. Port mapping doesn't work here since a client needs to talk to many servers with different or same port. What I am asking is if it is possible to treat the Windows client as part of the docker network. I read about tools such as weave net, etc., but haven't found anything useful. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't change what ports are used?

Comment: The clients running on other systems shouldn't need to change; if a server is running in a container on some system, the client can connect to the host's IP address and the published port (first `ports:` number) without knowing whether it's in Docker or not.